# For loop and If conditional statement not giving T/F

Tags: r

I am searching several large files for replicate gene entries. There are several duplicates and at least one triplcate entry in my list of genes.  I just want to be able to find out what lines are reps'!?!

I get the error:

```
Error in if (genes[i, 1] == genes[j, 1] && i != j) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am at a roadblock.

```
genes <- combine[c(4)]
num_rows <- nrow(genes)
dup_combine <- vector(mode="character", length=100)
n=1
for (i in 1:num_rows) {
only_check_rows <- num_rows-1
   for (j in i+1:only_check_rows) {
      if (genes[i,1] == genes[j,1]&&i!=j) {
         dup_combine[n] <- combine[i,1]
         n=n+1
         cat("i=",i,"j=",j,"\n")
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What about `duplicated`?

Comment: Aaron, I will look into 'duplicated', thanks for the tip.

Comment: I really like the 'duplicated' command but it does not tell me what is duplicated and where are the dups?  Any suggestions?

Comment: You are doing it terribly wrong. Try `table` or (faster) `rle` if the n-plicates are adjacent to each other.

Comment: All right MBQ, put your money where your mouth is?  The replicates are not necessarily next to each other but I need to find what and where they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are searching for duplicates in a single vector (`genes`). There are several ways to do this. Here's some example data:

```
dat <- c(1,2,3,2,4,4,6,NA,8,NA,13)
```

`table` will count the number of occurences of each unique value in `dat`. Note I use `exclude = NULL` to force it to count `NA` values as well:

```
table(dat, exclude = NULL)
```

As mentioned in a comment, `duplicated` also applies. This function returns a boolean vector indicating specifically which entries are duplicates of *previous* entries. `fromLast = TRUE` tells it to look from back to front, rather than from front to back.

```
duplicated(dat)
duplicated(dat, fromLast = TRUE)
```

You can combine these two directions to get *all* the duplicated elements:

```
subset(dat, duplicated(dat) | duplicated(dat, fromLast = TRUE))
```

If you are working with data frames, rather than single vectors, `duplicated` is probably the way to go.

*Edit*

Here's a short worked example using a sample data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,5,9),
        y = c(2,3,1,2,2,6,2,6,10))
> dat
  x  y
1 1  2
2 2  3
3 3  1
4 4  2
5 4  2
6 5  6
7 6  2
8 5  6
9 9 10

#Boolean vector of duplicated rows
duplicated(dat)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

#Indices of duplicated rows   
which(duplicated(dat))
[1] 5 8

#Look in both directions to get all dups (indices)
which(duplicated(dat) | duplicated(dat,fromLast = TRUE))
[1] 4 5 6 8

#The actual rows
subset(dat,duplicated(dat) | duplicated(dat, fromLast = TRUE))
  x y
4 4 2
5 4 2
6 5 6
8 5 6
```

> 

Comment: If I understand this (interesting) example then the output will not give me the name and position of the replicates. Is that true?

Comment: @oaxacamatt `duplicated` returns a boolean vector which is useful because it's more general that the specific info you're after. Wrap it in `which(...)` to get indices, or `rownames[duplicated(...)]` (data frame) `names[duplicated(...)]` (named vector) to get row/element names.

Answer (score 1):

The error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" happens if you give `if` `NA`. I suspect either

```
genes[i,1]
```

or

```
genes[j,1]
```

is `NA`, ie `genes` has some `NA`s in it. If you want to test equality where there might be `NA`, you can use

```
identical(genes[i,1], genes[j,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

As @joran wrote, you should use duplicated. But the problem with your code is because of faulty indexing...

When you index outside the array, you get NA back...

Something like this should work better:

```
for(i in seq_len(num_rows-1)) {
  for(j in (i+1):num_rows) {
    ...
```

Comment: Nice find in the OP's code.  I bet most of us (including myself) didn't bother to read it closely.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you have missing values in your data. Either `genes[i, 1]` or `genes[j, 1]` is returning a null, or NA. right after it fails, figure out what the values for i and j are and then look at that row. I suspect you'll be able to back into what's wrong.

Comment: what do you get for genes[i, 1] & genes[j, 1] at the point it breaks?